# Tic tac toe, o juego del gato

Tags: java

me encontré un código de el gato/tic tac toe en este foro, solo que era de jugador vs maquina y lo modifiqué para que sea de dos jugadores, pero tengo un problema y es que cuando gana el jugador 1 no me manda el mensaje de que ganó hasta que vuelve a tirar el segundo jugador, cuando gana el segundo si me manda directo el mensaje, espero que me puedan ayudar, ya no sé que mas poner, según yo la arte del jugador 1 como la del jugador 2 son iguales y no tendría por qué hacer que vuelva a tirar el segundo jugador para que me de el ganador

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

  public class Ggg {

    int espaciosDisponibles = 9;
    String tabla[][];
    char jugador;
    boolean ganadorJ2;
    boolean ganador;


    public Ggg() {
        tabla = new String[3][3];
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                tabla[x][y] = " ";
            }
        }
    
    }

    public void tablero() {
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            System.out.print("| ");
            for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {
                System.out.print(tabla[x][y] + " | ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public boolean encontrarGanadorJ2() {
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("O") && tabla[0][1].equals("O") && tabla[0][2].equals("O")) {
            ganadorJ2 = true;
        }
        if (tabla[1][0].equals("O") && tabla[1][1].equals("O") && tabla[1][2].equals("O")) {
            ganadorJ2 = true;
        }
        if (tabla[2][0].equals("O") && tabla[2][1].equals("O") && tabla[2][2].equals("O")) {
            ganadorJ2 = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("O") && tabla[1][0].equals("O") && tabla[2][0].equals("O")) {
            ganadorJ2 = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][1].equals("O") && tabla[1][1].equals("O") && tabla[2][1].equals("O")) {
            ganadorJ2 = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][2].equals("O") && tabla[1][2].equals("O") && tabla[2][2].equals("O")) {
            ganadorJ2 = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("O") && tabla[1][1].equals("O") && tabla[2][2].equals("O")) {
            ganadorJ2 = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][2].equals("O") && tabla[1][1].equals("O") && tabla[2][0].equals("O")) {
            ganadorJ2 = true;
        }
        return ganadorJ2;
    }

    public boolean encontrarGanadorJ1() {
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("X") && tabla[0][1].equals("X") && tabla[0][2].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[1][0].equals("X") && tabla[1][1].equals("X") && tabla[1][2].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[2][0].equals("X") && tabla[2][1].equals("X") && tabla[2][2].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("X") && tabla[1][0].equals("X") && tabla[2][0].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][1].equals("X") && tabla[1][1].equals("X") && tabla[2][1].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][2].equals("X") && tabla[1][2].equals("X") && tabla[2][2].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][0].equals("X") && tabla[1][1].equals("X") && tabla[2][2].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        if (tabla[0][2].equals("X") && tabla[1][1].equals("X") && tabla[2][0].equals("X")) {
            ganador = true;
        }
        return ganador;
    }

    public void jugada() {

        int x;
        int y;
        int xJ2;
        int yJ2;

        //Mientras no haya más espacios para jugar y no haya ganado ninguno
        while (espaciosDisponibles > 0 && !ganador && !ganadorJ2) {

            boolean espacioOcupado;

            do {
                //Verifica si hay por lo menos un espacio el que ocupar
                if (espaciosDisponibles > 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Turno del Jugador X");
                    x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Fila: 0 - 1 - 2"));
                    y = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Columna: 0 - 1 - 2"));
                    if (!tabla[x][y].equals("O") && !tabla[x][y].equals("X")) {
                        tabla[x][y] = "X";
                        espaciosDisponibles = espaciosDisponibles - 1;
                        espacioOcupado = true;
                    } else {
                        espacioOcupado = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    espacioOcupado = true;
                }
            } while (!espacioOcupado);
            //Cada vez que se ingresa una posicion, se debe imprimir el tablero y verificar si ganamos
            tablero();
            ganador = encontrarGanadorJ1();
            ganadorJ2 = encontrarGanadorJ2();

            
            //Mientras el espacio generado (x,y) automaticamente esta en uso se generara otro
            do {
                //Verifica si hay por lo menos un espacio el que ocupar
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Turno del Jugador O");
                if (espaciosDisponibles > 0) {
                    x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Fila: 0 - 1 - 2"));
                    y = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Columna: 0 - 1 - 2"));
                    if (!tabla[x][y].equals("O") && !tabla[x][y].equals("X")) {
                        tabla[x][y] = "O";
                        espaciosDisponibles = espaciosDisponibles - 1;
                        espacioOcupado = true;
                    } else {
                        espacioOcupado = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    espacioOcupado = true;
                }
            } while (!espacioOcupado);
            //Cada vez que se genera una posicion, se imprime la tabla y se verifica si la J2uina gano
            tablero();
            ganadorJ2 = encontrarGanadorJ2();
            ganador = encontrarGanadorJ1();
        }
    }

    public void verificarGanador() {
        if (ganador) {
            System.out.println("Ganó el jugador 1!");
        } else if (ganadorJ2) {
            System.out.println("Ganó el jugador 2!");
        } else if (espaciosDisponibles == 0) {
            System.out.println("Empate, vuelvan a jugar");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ggg gat = new Ggg();
        gat.jugada();
        gat.verificarGanador();
    }
}
```

Comment: No es una respuesta a tu problema, pero ¿Te das cuenta de que los métodos encontrarGanadorJ2 y encontrarGanadorJ1 son lo mismo variando la letra que buscas? podrías crear un método `encontrarGanador(String x)` y llamarlo con X y con O, ahorrándote mucho código repetido

Comment: @PabloLozano soy nuevo en esto, voy en primer semestre,  el código lo encontré así solo modfiqué que jugaba contra la maquina, me podrías orientar mejor para hacer lo que dices?